# The [booking] has been cancelled

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

Oh dear, [booking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/booking). 9 followers and 60 questions, with many excessively vague "how do I write a booking system?"-style questions that have somehow avoided the Roomba.

- #### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

  No, the questions are usually about APIs for booking systems.
- #### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

  No, it's really a meta-tag.
- #### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

  Other than notifying me that this is probably a poor question, no.
- #### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

  Yes, I suppose, but all the common contexts are off-topic.

I've noticed there is a [woocommerce-bookings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce-bookings) which appears to be OK, so we could retag some of the questions with that, I think.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q:  +60/0. No answers

Comment: Can we cancel all [booking]s?

Comment: An argument for setting "mean the same thing" to "No": In [at least](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51712282/) [two cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758397/), they're specifically referring to booking.com: One is to pull calendar data, one is to embed a booking.com search "widget."

Comment: I'd thank Capt Obvious for this burninate, but he works for Hotels.com

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +94/-1. A1 (saying No): +5/-25 A2 (saying Yes): 13/-1. A3 (saying Yes) +0/0. The community has voted in favor of burnination.

Answer (score 12):

I really really don't like [booking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/booking) for booking.com questions; [booking.com-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/booking.com-api) (which doesn't seem to exist yet) would be much better.

I read the Q list and couldn't get a grasp on what else is going on; seems to be a a mess to me too.

I'm for burninating the tag unless somebody steps up and defends it and is willing to provide usage guidelines.

I received notice via an unhelpful edit that the booking.com API is commercial access only. Can someone look up the policy on such API questions? I don't know if that makes all booking.com API questions on topic or not.

Comment: Will the downvoter please post an answer.

Comment: Why would we need a [booking.com] tag? Only 7 mention that site and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46797294/get-property-rating-from-booking-com-api) says they don't have a public API

Comment: @Machavity: Maybe you don't. The suggestion was in the question as a reason somebody might want to save the booking tag.

Comment: @Machavity [They do have an API](https://developers.booking.com/api/commercial/index.html?version=2.2&page_url=getting-started).... Anyway, I don't agree with the answer completely. [booking.com] would be a great tag to harbor off topic posts about the site rather than the api. [booking.com-api] would perhaps be better.

Comment: @BhargavRao Yeah, it's [relatively new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004435/booking-com-hotel-management-api). I could live with a -api tag

Comment: @BhargavRao: Changed answer to booking.com-api as that's better yet.

Answer (score 4):

[tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Retag with the [woocommerce-bookings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce-bookings) tag when the question is related to Woocommerce Bookings.
- Retag with the [booking.com-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/booking.com-api) tag when the question is asking any programming questions about the booking.com API.

## Progress:

The [booking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/booking) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=booking),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbooking%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbooking%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbooking%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbooking%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [booking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/booking) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [booking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/booking) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [booking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/booking) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a useless tag for a number of reasons.

First, it no longer has a tag Wiki guidance. While that can be remedied, it's not clear what the usage guidance should even be because it's unclear what the tag is for.

Secondly, this tag is (as the question states) extremely vague.

Third, even if we say that this is specifically about booking systems, the vagueness of this aside, it's unclear why we have this tag to begin with. What's so "special" about booking systems vs. other kinds of programming? Even apart from the burnination criteria, why do we even need this tag? It's pointless at best if there's no specific programming expertise associated with it. It's simply not adding any on-topic information to the program - after all, questions about booking systems could be virtually any kind of programming question under the sun.

Besides, if we say that we should keep this tag, why not have tags for *every* kind of system out there? Why not have tags for administrative software, hospital management systems, or whatever other kinds of software systems that people work on?

Comment: The only reason I'm even considering making a booking.com-api is there are are questions already for it.

Comment: @Joshua That would be reasonable because it's asking about a specific API, which presumably *does* require some specific programming knowledge. I don't see how asking about booking systems in general requires a specific kind of programming knowledge, though, which significantly reduces the value of the tag for our site.